# Optimize Perl script to deal with large amount of data

Tags: perl

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

`rm /slot/ems12093/oracle/working/marchfound.txt`;
`touch /slot/ems12093/oracle/working/marchfound.txt`;

`rm /slot/ems12093/oracle/working/newcontact.txt`;
`touch /slot/ems12093/oracle/working/newcontact.txt`;

my ( $filename, $handle, @contact_list, $file_list, $k, @file_list2, $i, $e, $m, $fh, $f, $g,
    $file1, $data, $file_location, $arrSize, $namefile );

$file_location = '/slot/ems12093/oracle/working/marchfound.txt';
$filename      = '/slot/ems12093/oracle/working/contact.txt';

open( $handle, '<', $filename ) or die $!;
@contact_list = <$handle>;
close $handle;

chomp @contact_list;

chdir( '/scratch/mount_point/dnbfiles/oracle_cr/' );
$file_list = qx(ls|grep -i \"2016_03_Mar_EA\");
chomp( $file_list );

$k = "/scratch/mount_point/dnbfiles/oracle_cr/2016_03_Mar_EA";
chdir( $k );

@file_list2 = qx(ls|grep -i contact|grep -i full|grep -Ev "Glb");
chomp @file_list2;

foreach $file1 ( @file_list2 ) {

    foreach $i ( @contact_list ) {

        $e = "zgrep $i $file1";
        $f = qx($e);

        if ( $f ) {
            print "working\n";

            $g = "$f, $file1";

            open $data, '>>', $file_location or die $!;
            print $data "$g\n";
            close $data;

            @contact_list = grep { !/$i/ } @contact_list;
            $arrSize = @contact_list;
            print "$arrSize\n";
        }
    }

}

$m = "/slot/ems12093/oracle/working/";
chdir( $m );

chomp @contact_list;
$namefile = '/slot/ems12093/oracle/working/newcontact.txt';
open( $fh, '<', $namefile ) or die $!;
@contact_list = <$fh>;
close $fh;

print "done\n";
```

Here I am taking an input file `contact.txt` which has 370k records, for example mail address, and checking if those records are present in March month's zipped database `2016_03_Mar_EA`.

The database again contains approx 1.6 million records e.g. name, designation, mail, etc. So it's going to take a LOT of time to check and print all 355k * 1.6m records.

Please suggest if there is any way that I can improve my script to get a faster result.

Comment: It would be easier to figure out what you are trying to do if you didn't use one-letter variable names, but used descriptive names instead.  Please rewrite your question with better variables so we can follow along.

Comment: Don't use array for this :`@contact_list = <$handle>;`, Use while loop like this `while(my $contact_row = <$handle>){ chomp($contact_row); do_stuff;  }`close  $handle; and follow @xxfelixxx instructions.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches

Comment: @xxfelixxx i am not comparing 2 columns here, input contains only mail ids and we are checking in files which has more data about a person including mail id.

Comment: `-w` and `use warnings` do pretty much the same thing. You don't need `-w` if you have `use warnings`. Backticks are used when you want to capture the output from the external command. You probably want to use `system()` instead (but you can also use Perl's own `unlink()` function instead of a call to an external program). Using `glob()` or File::Find will be more efficient than shelling out to `ls` and `grep`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but is there a reason for the `-E` in `grep -Ev "Glb"`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You do not pose a specific question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not purely speed specific but you should do below modifications.

1) contact.txt has 370k records therefore you should not slurp whole data at once. So instead of doing

```
@contact_list = <$handle>;
```

You should read data line by line using

```
while(<$handle>){
    #process one contact at a time
}
```

2) You are changing directories and executing shell commands to get desired files. It'd be better to use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule). It's easier to use, see below:

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name( '*.pm' )->in( @INC );
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The way you are doing this, I'd bet most of the time is spent in umcompressing the database dump (which will happen 370k times). Uncompress it once - before doing the matches. (That assumes you do have enough disk).
2. If you are not checking for actual regexps, fgrep will save some (marginal) time (though I suspect that this optimizatin is done internally by grep)
3. The advice on not slurping files is a good for memory saving, and should not affect speed much, for a single scan through the data. However, you are actually unnecessarily scanning the arry multiple times, in order to get rid of duplicate contacts

   @contact_list = grep { !/$i/ } @contact_list;

and that not always slows the whole shebang down, it also wastes memory as  @contact_list is being copied in memory.

You can read by line, keep track in a hash, and skip the loop body on duplicates:

```
next if exists $seen{$i};
$seen{$i}++
```